# Beer recommendations for India, please

Tags: recommendations

Which is the good brew for India? I generally prefer Budweiser and I am pretty much good with it.

Comment: I was amazed by how popular Budweiser was in India (although I don't usually drink it). Pretty common actually.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In India, We have many foreign brews available. Some of my favorites are in rank-wise order:
1. Hoegaarden(Belgian Brewed)
2. Stella Artois(Again Belgian Brewed)
3. Erdinger(German Brewed)

Also I recommend you to try Ballantine Ale, American Brewed Beer..

These Royal Lagers are worth giving a try!! Cheers!

Answer (score 6):

As in every country exist brands most famous inside India too.

The five brands are:

- Kingfisher (4.8% grade - strong 8%)
- Haywards (7%)
- Royal Challenge (5%)
- Kalyani Black Label (7.8%)
- Kings (4.8%)

Personally I've tried Kalyani Black Label and I think is very good (is important the personal taste when you drink a beer bottle).

Unfortunately I haven't tried other four beer in upper list.

Comment: Does Cobra feature on that list? Although, as I've recently found out; it's mostly brewed in the UK apparently?!

Answer (score 2):

My favoured beer is Erdinger but it is priced high due to import duties. Of the local fare, UB's London Pilsner & Kingfisher Blue are my favourites

Answer (score 1):

Different people have different tastes. For me, I like much hard beer, Budweiser is pretty much mild for me. In hot days, I look for chilled Cobra, if it's not available, I settle for Touborg strong

Comment: What do you mean by "hard beer"? ...Strong? (But _regular_ Budweiser has a higher advertised AbV than _regular_ Cobra? Unless you're referring to King Cobra 7.5%?)

Comment: Yes I was referring King, and elephant is also good, the taste is not fine though